# Bid Price in AWS Instance Fleets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-emr

I am using instance fleets via boto3 run_job_flow() to create an aws cluster. I keep getting this error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RunJobFlow operation: The bid price is invalid. Revise the configuration and resubmit.
```

I can't figure out what it doesn't like about my_bid_price variable. I have tried submitting `0.50` or `OnDemandPrice` - both as strings. Also tried `0.50` as a float. None of these work. However, when I remove the BidPrice key from the dictionary altogether, it does submit as OnDemandPrice.

I am using boto3 1.12.28 and botocore 1.22.5.

What am I missing? I have simplified the dict I'm passing, but it still produces the same error:

```
config = {
'Applications': [],
'BootstrapActions': [
    {
        'Name': 'bootstrap',
        'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
            'Path': my_bootstrap_path
        }
    }
],
'Configurations': [
    {
        'Classification': 'emrfs-site',
        'Properties': {
            'fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption': 'true'
        },
        'Configurations': []
    },
    {
        'Classification': 'spark-env',
        'Configurations': [
            {
                'Classification': 'export',
                'Properties': {
                    'PYSPARK_PYTHON': '/usr/bin/python3'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
'Instances': {
    'Ec2SubnetIds': my_emr_subnet_ids,
    'EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup': my_emr_master_sg,
    'EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup': my_emr_node_sg,
    'InstanceFleets': [ 
        {
            'Name': 'My Master Node',
            'InstanceFleetType': 'MASTER',
            'InstanceTypeConfigs': [
                { 
                    'BidPrice': my_bid_price,
                    'EbsConfiguration': { 
                        'EbsBlockDeviceConfigs': [ 
                            { 
                                'VolumeSpecification': { 
                                    'SizeInGB': my_core_ebs_size,
                                    'VolumeType': my_core_ebs_volume_type
                                },
                                'VolumesPerInstance': my_core_ebs_volumes
                            }
                        ],
                        'EbsOptimized': True
                    },
                    'InstanceType': my_master_instance_type,
                    'WeightedCapacity': 1
                }
            ],
            'TargetOnDemandCapacity': 1
        },
        {
            'Name': 'My Core Node',
            'InstanceFleetType': 'CORE',
            'InstanceTypeConfigs': [
                { 
                    'BidPrice': my_bid_price,
                    'EbsConfiguration': { 
                        'EbsBlockDeviceConfigs': [ 
                            { 
                                'VolumeSpecification': { 
                                    'SizeInGB': my_core_ebs_size,
                                    'VolumeType': my_core_ebs_volume_type
                                },
                                'VolumesPerInstance': my_core_ebs_volumes
                            }
                        ],
                        'EbsOptimized': True
                    },
                    'InstanceType': my_core_node_instance_type,
                    'WeightedCapacity': 1
                }
            ],
            'TargetSpotCapacity': my_num_core_nodes
        }
    ],
    'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': my_keep_alive,
    'ServiceAccessSecurityGroup': my_emr_access_sg,
},
'JobFlowRole': 'MyJobFlowRole',
'LogUri': my_log_uri,
'Name': my_cluster_name,
'ReleaseLabel': my_release_label,
'ServiceRole': 'MyRole',
'StepConcurrencyLevel': my_step_concurrency,
'Tags': [],
'VisibleToAllUsers': True
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work, I needed to remove the `bid_price` key when submitting a fleet with On Demand pricing. I was passing the string `OnDemandPrice` as the value for the `bid_price` key, which boto3 did not like.